# Making a dynamic RSS feed from external XML file

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am trying to generate an RSS feed for a streamate whitelabel site.  The network support have provided me with the bare minimum information on how to generate anything.

This is all they have provided to generate info about live performers:

*"This query is used to retrieve information about performers. 
You will receive the information packaged into an XML document.
Please send your XML request by HTTP POST to:
http://affliate.streamate.com/??????/SMLResult.xml
Be sure to send a “Content-type: text/xml” header as part of the HTTP request. You
may replace streamate.com with a branded domain, if one is available to you, to have
URLs returned with that same branded domain instead of streamate.com"*

So, I have managed to find out how to pull live info from their XML feed into a php page, by searching for a snippet of code, but this is not an RSS feed that I can utilise (to feed into social networks, etc).

If anyone can please give me some pointers on how to utilise their XML file into an RSS feed which links to my own whitelabe domain (as they have half instructed above).

Below is the code I have found and used to generate the live info on a php page (I just wish it was an RSS feed).

```
<?php
$curlData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SMLQuery>
    <Options MaxResults="20"/>
    <AvailablePerformers Exact="false" PageNum="1" CountTotalResults="true">
    <Include>
    <Country/>
    <Headline/>
    <Descriptions></Descriptions>
    <Rating/>
    <Age/>
    <Gender/>
    <Media>biopic</Media>
    <FreeChatSort/>
    <PerformanceSort/>
    </Include>
    <Constraints> <StreamType>live,recorded,offline</StreamType>
    <PublicProfile/>
    <Name></Name><NoKeywords/>
    <RelativeURLs/>
    <NoKeywords/>
    </Constraints>
    </AvailablePerformers>
    </SMLQuery>';

$url='http://affiliate.streamate.com/????/SMLResult.xml';
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array ('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8',));
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlData);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);

$xml = simplexml_load_string ($result);
// $json = json_encode($xml);
// $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

print_r ($result);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Cam Testing Going On :)</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="streamstyle.css" />
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="home">

<?php
foreach ($xml->AvailablePerformers->Performer as $perf) {
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<p>";
    echo "<strong>Name: </strong>" .$perf->attributes()->Name ."<br />";
    echo "<a href='http://www.mywhitelabeldomain.com/cam/".$perf->attributes()->Name."/?AFNO=X-0-XXXXXX-XXXXXX&UHNSMTY=XXX' target='_blank'><img src='http://mywhitelabeldomain.com".$perf->Media->Pic->Thumb->attributes()->Src."' /></a><br />";
    echo "<strong>Age: </strong>" .$perf->attributes()->Age ."<br />";
    echo "<strong>About: </strong>" .$perf->attributes()->Headline ."<br />";
    echo "<strong>Description: </strong>" .$perf->Descriptions->About ."<br />";
    echo "<strong>StreamType: </strong>" .$perf->attributes()->StreamType ."<br />";
    echo "<p>";
    echo "<br />";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is one of the example snippets that the affiliate network provided, which I can see is part of the above code I found:

XML Request Structure
Example, Real World Generic

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SMLQuery>
<Options MaxResults="50" />
<AvailablePerformers QueryId=”MyGenericQuery”>
<Include>
<Descriptions />
<Media>staticbiopic</Media>
</Include>
<Constraints>
<PublicProfile />
<StreamType>live</StreamType>
</Constraints>
</AvailablePerformers>
</SMLQuery>
```

Thanks for any advice anyone can give me. I really want to learn how to do this.

I am aware that an RSS feed xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <rss version="2.0"> <channel> <title>Website Feed</title> <description>Website Feed coded manually</description> <link>yourdomain.com</link>; <item> <title>A Special Event</title> <description>A Special Teleconference for our customers about our products</description> <link>yourdomain.com/events.htm</link>; </item> </channel> </rss>
```

But I am wanting to combine the data from the external xml file (from my first code snippet at the begining of this post) into an rss feed xml file, but retaining the use of my whitelabel url in the links.

UPDATE

Ok, I have tried merging some of the php code into an xml doc using an rss feed code structure, but obviously I am failing as I do not quite understand what I am doing here.  I have searched google endlessly on this.  Here is my attempt at merging the codes:

```
<?php
$curlData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SMLQuery>
<Options MaxResults="20"/>
<AvailablePerformers Exact="false" PageNum="1" CountTotalResults="true">
<Include>
<Country/>
<Headline/>
<Descriptions></Descriptions>
<Rating/>
<Age/>
<Gender/>
<Media>biopic</Media>
<FreeChatSort/>
<PerformanceSort/>
</Include>
<Constraints> <StreamType>live,recorded,offline</StreamType>
<PublicProfile/>
<Name></Name><NoKeywords/>
<RelativeURLs/>
<NoKeywords/>
</Constraints>
</AvailablePerformers>
</SMLQuery>';
$url='http://affiliate.streamate.com/?????/SMLResult.xml';
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
'Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8',
));
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlData);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);

$xml = simplexml_load_string ($result);
// $json = json_encode($xml);
// $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

print_r ($result);
?>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<rss version="2.0"> 
<channel> 
<title>Website Feed</title> 
<description>Website Feed coded manually</description>
<link>yourdomain.com</link>; 

<?php
foreach ($xml->AvailablePerformers->Performer as $perf) {

<item> 
<title><php? echo ".$perf->attributes()->Name ."?></title> 
<description><php? echo " .$perf->Descriptions->About ."?></description> 
<link><php? echo "<a href='http://www.mydomain.com/cam/".$perf->attributes()->Name."    /?AFNO=X-0-XXXXXX-XXXXXX&UHNSMTY=XXX?></link>; 
</item> 
</channel>
</rss>
?>
```

UPDATE 2

I have removed the print_r() as instructed and saved the following code as a php file, uploaded it, but all I am seeing is a blank white page.  I dont know what to change re the header tag so can you explain where the header code should be and what I need to add/change please?

This is the code I now have, saved as a php file (or should it be an xml file? as I want it as an RSS feed, not a php webpage).

```
<?php
$curlData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <SMLQuery>
<Options MaxResults="20"/>
<AvailablePerformers Exact="false" PageNum="1" CountTotalResults="true">
<Include>
<Country/>
<Headline/>
<Descriptions></Descriptions>
<Rating/>
<Age/>
<Gender/>
<Media>biopic</Media>
<FreeChatSort/>
<PerformanceSort/>
</Include>
<Constraints> <StreamType>live,recorded,offline</StreamType>
<PublicProfile/>
<Name></Name><NoKeywords/>
<RelativeURLs/>
<NoKeywords/>
</Constraints>
        </AvailablePerformers>
</SMLQuery>';
$url='http://affiliate.streamate.com/?????/SMLResult.xml';
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
'Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8',
));
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlData);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);

$xml = simplexml_load_string ($result);
// $json = json_encode($xml);
// $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);


?>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<rss version="2.0"> 
<channel> 
<title>Website Feed</title> 
<description>Website Feed coded manually</description>
<link>yourdomain.com</link>; 

<?php
foreach ($xml->AvailablePerformers->Performer as $perf) {

<item> 
<title><php? echo ".$perf->attributes()->Name ."?></title> 
<description><php? echo " .$perf->Descriptions->About ."?></description> 
<link><php? echo "<a href='http://www.mydomain.com/cam/".$perf->attributes()->Name."    /?AFNO=X-0-XXXXXX-XXXXXX&UHNSMTY=XXX?></link> 
</item> 
</channel>
</rss>
?>
```

Just bumping this thread in hope someone can assist? Thanks.

UPDATE

ok I understand that I need to set the header content type. I have searched the web and found this:

```
<?php
header("Content-type:rss/xml");
?>
```

Is this correct for an rss feed?  Where exactly in the page do I put this?

Also yet in my original code pasted above there is already a bit of code relating to content type stating:

```
'Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8',
));
```

All I want is my original code to be an RSS Feed. I can't believe how difficult this is proving to find information on.

Comment: Hi, not sure what you mean by "what have I tried so far"? I have explained everything I have tried above in my initial post.  Basically I have managed to generate a php webpage from a remote xml file, but I am having difficulty creating an RSS feed from that data.  All is explained in my first post.  Any advice would be greatly apprecated as I am totally stock at this point. Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone please assist? I am completely stuck on this.

Comment: What I mean by "What had you tried so far?" is exactly that. You have not shown that you have made any effort to modify the data returned by the XML feed into an RSS feed. You have just shown how you are getting the original feed and saying you are stuck.  Stuck on what? What specific problem are you having when you try to parse through the initial XML result and convert to RSS? So far all you have shown is that you are trying to output HTML based on the original XML feed. Where is the code where you try to make this into an RSS feed?

Comment: I tried to paste code in here but it is saying I am over characters. I know how to make a static RSS feed, but I am struggling to combine the code I posted originally within an rss feed document. For example the feed will not work with php code in.

Comment: Here is a basic feed code:
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rss version="2.0">
        <channel>
            <title>Website Feed</title>
            <description>Website Feed coded manually</description>
            <link>http://www.yourdomain.com</link>
                <item>
                    <title>A Special Event</title>
                    <description>A Special Teleconference for our customers about our products</description>
                    <link>http://www.yourdomain.com/events.htm</link>
                </item>
                
        </channel>
    </rss>

Comment: I need to learn  how to combine php (from my first post) into an rss feed document, but an rss is a xml doc and php doesn't seem to work in xml files. Am I right?

Comment: You can edit your original post to add more code (that is preferable to trying to add it in comments). Basically, all you are doing is trying to output an XML document right?  So really there are two aspects to it, using PHP to send the proper Content-type header, and using PHP to output the XML structure. At the most simplistic level, you should be able to loop through your received XML content and output the XML structure required for RSS.

Comment: thanks Mike, well its a bit more complicated as I am a whitelabel owner so the links in the feed will need to link to my domain, not the streamate domain.  Infact the affiliate network, suggest changing this within the code.  Which I did in the first php code which posts to a php webpage.  I need the same action but within RSS feed.

Comment: Are there any example codes I could try to at least start an rss with data from the external xml file?  Maybe from then we can look at the domain aspect? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need sample code?  Outputting XML is not different than outputting HTML in PHP.  You just have a different tag structure.  The should be nothing stopping you you from giving this a shot right now.

Comment: I can output the xml into html and php, the problem is I do not know how to output the remote xml info into an rss feed I can use.  So basically I need the remote xml info to RSS.  Am I correct in that RSS feeds have to also be xml files? or can they be php files?

Comment: RSS is just a specific XML format.  It seems you already have the functionality to read the remote XML into SimpleXML, and based on your update, it looks like you have figured out the formatting for RSS. You should update your question with the specific problem you are now having.  There are 2 things you definiteiyl need to do through.  Remove the `print_r()` once you are happy with `$result` as this will break XML.  And you need to set an appropriate Content-type header using `header()`.

Comment: I've added update 2 but unfortunately still having many problems. I am stuck on where to change the header, and what to change exactly.

Comment: Just bumping my problem in hope someone can assist today. Thanks. My problem is how to change the header as suggested by Mike Brant.  I am struggling to find out exactly where and what I change within my code as pasted in my latest update or my original post.

Comment: Read the documentation on PHP's `header()` function or Google something like "PHP set Content type header"

Answer (score 0):

You want to turn your example into a usable RSS feed you can plug into your WL and other types of sites. This is very easy with what you had previously. As an example lets pretend you create a PHP page on the example domain below:

hxxp://www.example.com/pull_xml.php

Put inside it this content:

```
<?php
$curlData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SMLQuery>
<Options MaxResults="20"/>
<AvailablePerformers Exact="false" PageNum="1" CountTotalResults="true">
<Include>
<Country/>
<Headline/>
<Descriptions></Descriptions>
<Rating/>
<Age/>
<Gender/>
<Media>biopic</Media>
<FreeChatSort/>
<PerformanceSort/>
</Include>
<Constraints> <StreamType>live,recorded,offline</StreamType>
<PublicProfile/>
<Name></Name><NoKeywords/>
<RelativeURLs/>
<NoKeywords/>
</Constraints>
</AvailablePerformers>
</SMLQuery>';

$url='http://affiliate.streamate.com/????/SMLResult.xml';
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array ('Content-Type: application/xml;       charset=utf-8',));
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlData);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);

echo $result;

?>
```

When you load that page into your browser you will see that it is an XML feed suitable for filling up your WL. To create a specific RSS feed from the data to work with a proprietary format expected by a certain service you will have to update your question with what format the feed should take. You can give an example of a feed you wish to emulate.

Also, you can change all URL's to your WL's URL structure by asking for the stream and substituting streamate.com with your whitelabel's domain.