# generating an RSS Feed from remote xml data

Tags: php, xml, curl, rss

I am trying to make an RSS feed which feeds live data from a remote XML file provided to me for promoting a webcam network.

I want to run a feed within my official website. My problem is, I want to output the data into an RSS feed. I am not too familiar with RSS and php so there is a lot of guess work going on.

Here is the code I have so far which will not work, it incorporates php to retrieve the xml data. Also I am unsure as to what filename/type I save this as? XML or php? Both don't seem to work.

```
<?php
$curlData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SMLQuery>
<Options MaxResults="20"/>
<AvailablePerformers Exact="false" PageNum="1" CountTotalResults="true">
<Include>
<Country/>
<Headline/>
<Descriptions></Descriptions>
<Rating/>
<Age/>
<Gender/>
<Media>biopic</Media>
<FreeChatSort/>
<PerformanceSort/>
</Include>
<Constraints> <StreamType>live,recorded,offline</StreamType>
<PublicProfile/>
<Name></Name><NoKeywords/>
<RelativeURLs/>
<NoKeywords/>
</Constraints>
</AvailablePerformers>
</SMLQuery>';
$url='http://affiliate.streamate.com/?????/SMLResult.xml';
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
'Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8',
));
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlData);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);

$xml = simplexml_load_string ($result);
// $json = json_encode($xml);
// $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);


?>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<rss version="2.0"> 
<channel> 
<title>Website Feed</title> 
    <description>Website Feed coded manually</description>
<link>yourdomain.com</link>; 

<?php
foreach ($xml->AvailablePerformers->Performer as $perf) {

<item> 
<title><php? echo ".$perf->attributes()->Name ."?></title> 
<description><php? echo " .$perf->Descriptions->About ."?></description> 
<link><php? echo "<a href='http://www.example.com        /cam/".$perf->attributes()->Name."    /?AFNO=X-0-XXXXXX-XXXXXX&UHNSMTY=XXX?></link> 
</item> 
</channel>
</rss>
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a dynamic RSS feed from external XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323918/making-a-dynamic-rss-feed-from-external-xml-file) - Please do not duplicate your existing question only because you haven't had an answer so far. Instead edit your previous question and improve it. And if I may add: After you describe what you intend to do, also write in your own words with what exactly (the small problem) you got stuck. That should give you better pointers.

Answer (score -1):

As you already have an XML source and want another XML result, maybe you could try XSLT to directly convert it.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: Better to show an example than just provide a link.  Link only answers are often deleted. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers